# Attachments in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uri

I have to attach some files on a `UIWebView`. In order to get the content of the files, I'll have to do an HTTP GET request. I know how to get the file content (it can be any file, binary data, etc), but I can't find out how to create an attachment link on the `UIWebView` which would either save the http response data, or the uri for the http request, so that I show the content after clicking on the attachment link. Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't this be automatically done if you create an HTML page including the attachment links you need to display and loading that HTML into the UIWebView using `-loadHTMLString:baseURL:`?

Comment: My question is how do I create the attachment links at the end of the UIWebView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly your question, you would like:

1. to download some files by sending
   out HTTP GET requests and storing
   them locally (in the app's document
   folder);
2. show a `UIWebView` with links to
   the downloaded documents;

whereby you already know how to deal with (1).

if this is correct, for (2), you can create an `htmlString`:

```
<html><head>...</head><body>...
<a href="attachment1.ext">link to 1st doc</a>
....
<a href="attachment2.ext">link to nth doc</a>
...
</body></html>
```

then initialize a `UIWebView` and load the `htmlString` into it by executing:

```
[_label loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath]];
```

where `basePath` is the path to the folder where you have stored the documents you downloaded.
Setting the `basePath` value will ensure that the `href`s you specified in the html will find your locally stored files.
basePath could be your app's Documents folder or whatever you chose it to be when storing locally the files, I suppose you know what it is.

(in the html above, replace `attachment*.ext` with the actual filenames)

If I haven't correctly understood your workflow, please elaborate more.